# Get attribute value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a loop that will get data from certain buttons with certain classes.
This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<button class="see" price="5">First</button>
<button class="see" price="8">Second</button>
<button class="see" price="10">Third</button>
```

I want a loop that can do something like this:

```
while($("see").attr("price")) {
    if($("see").attr("price") + 5 > 10) {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

I want to loop trough the buttons, and get an alert once the buttons "price" attribute is greater than e.g 10.

Sorry for the poorly description, I can't explain it any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the buttons.see using the function `each` and convert to number every attribute `price`.

This selector `.see[price]` gets the elements with class `see` and with the attribute `price`.

```js
$(".see[price]").each(function() {
  if (+$(this).attr("price") + 5 > 10) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="see" price="5">First</button>
<button class="see" price="8">Second</button>
<button class="see" price="10">Third</button>
```

I recommend you to use `data-attributes` for unknown attributes:

```js
$(".see[data-price]").each(function() {
  if (+$(this).data("price") + 5 > 10) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="see" data-price="5">First</button>
<button class="see" data-price="8">Second</button>
<button class="see" data-price="10">Third</button>
```

Comment: There are about 3 issues I can see in the original questions code that converting to a number is the least of their worries

Comment: Explicitly converting to a number isn't necessary here. The types will be coerced upon comparison - for example, go to your browser's JavaScript console and type in `8 + 3 > "10"`, which will result in `true`. The same will happen when you type in `8 + 3 > 10`. The main problem with the OP's code was the infinite loop, and `$("see")` was missing a period to indicate the selector was targeting a class, as in `$(".see")`

Comment: @ryanm It's necessary because `"8" + 5 === "85"` and `+"8" + 5 === 13`.

Comment: @Ele +1 on pointing out what happens when I incorrectly place the `" "`